# How i copy the content of selected row

Tags: livecode

How I copy the selected content in a row. With the help of following code I got the line number of the row. but i don't have any idea to copy the content of the particular row

```
on mouseUp
   put the dgHilitedLines of group "data" into theLine
   answer theLine
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the global clipboarddata property to set the clipboard:

```
on mouseUp
   put the dgHilitedLines of group "data" into myLine
   set the clipboarddata["text"] to line myLine of the dgText \
     of grp "data"
end mouseUp
```